# Is there any free video screen capture applications?

Tags: video, video-capture, screen-casting

I am trying to find a totally free screen capture application for Windows and MacOS. Is there any free apps that don't put watermark on the video ?

Answer (score 2):

[Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) is a (good)

> Free and open source software for video recording and live streaming.
>   Download and start streaming quickly and easily on Windows, Mac or
>   Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Gyan that [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/) is probably the best free tool.

Or if you have an ATI videocard you probably have Radeon Software installed which can Record & Stream. Ofcourse you don't have to stream.

Also VLC can do it. It's tucked away beneath: Media tab -> Convert / Save option -> Capture Device.

Answer (score -1):

I'm often using [Calipio](https://calipio.com/) to record my screen, which is free for up to 20mins of recordings.

Comment: The person asks for a totally free software and the one you mention isn't.

Comment: Hey Matt, the initial poster doesn't give a lot of information on what he needs it for. If he needs to record short videos it is "totally" free. If he needs it for more than 20mins then you're right.